# Ubuntu 12.04 not loading after removing Wine

Tags: wine, uninstall

I used the following command to get rid of Wine on my Ubuntu 12.04 system but instead it got rid of everything!

`sudo apt-get remove wine*`

Now when I try to load my Ubuntu I get the following:

```
The system is running in low-graphics mode

Your screen, graphic cards, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself."
```

When I try to configure myself I click "Restore from Default" but nothing happens.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Welp, be more careful with the `*` character next time, it means `everything`.

[Here's](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) a guide on Ubuntu data recovery. Depending on what happened it might be possible to recover some things. If you really removed everything a lot of messages would'v appeared - you could'v pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to interrupt it. If that's the case, then unless you made a backup of your applications [it's not possible to restore them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56095/how-i-do-a-system-restore). On the other hand, your data such as documents, pictures, etc, probably were NOT lost.

You can [boot without X](https://superuser.com/questions/102376/boot-ubuntu-without-x) and make a backup of your files before re installing Ubuntu. Check [`how to copy files from terminal`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195983/how-to-copy-files-via-terminal) if you don't know how to do it. While in console mode, use `man command` or `command --help` to get more info - replacing `command` with the command you need help with. `ls` lists directory and files, `ls -R` does it recursively, i.e. searching sub directories.

Answer (score 1):

This problem could be solved by reinstalling ubuntu-desktop.

When the message that "your system is running in low-graphics mode" appears, 
press 
**`Ctrl+Alt+F1`**, then login with your credentials.

And then, run the following commands:

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
>
> sudo reboot