# How to get back unity and compiz after uninstalling, no launcher or dash on startup

Tags: unity, 14.04, compiz, launcher, reset

I've gone through a ton of threads regarding this issue with nothing working for me. I removed compiz to reinstall it (foolishly) and I just can't seem to get unity back. I'm on 14.04.

[The Unity Plugin is checked in Compiz Config Settings Manager.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

[image]

I've tried uninstalling everything and reinstalling everything.

```
sudo apt-get remove compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get remove compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get purge compiz*

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install git compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
sudo apt-get install unity
```

One thing that I think my problem might be is that I can't get a connection with dconf.

When I try solutions like this:

```
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

or like this

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

I get a *huge* list of errors like

```
dconf-WARNING**: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: Connection refused
dconf-WARNING**: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

Anyone have other suggestions for how I can fix this? I'm desperate not to have to reinstall the operating system altogether.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I had simmilar problems not long ago, this fixed the problem for me:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

This will force the reinstall without keeping the configuration files, that seem to be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Re-installing `ubuntu-desktop` has no effect, because that's just a meta-package, and is therefore pointless. Contrarily to what you claim, `apt-get install --reinstall` doesn't modify any configuration files – especially not those residing in user directories like those of compiz – (unless there's a package update that would overwrite modifications to the system configuration files).

Comment: I think that works but in my case I had a compiz profile backed up and did the purge and resinstall then imported the profile

Answer (score 0):

I have messed up my system like this also.  (I uninstalled a default system component and a large number of packages went with it.) I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

System settings is now available again and all system setting applets are back.

With further research I discovered [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56095/how-i-do-a-system-restore) ....

Actually, there are few things in Ubuntu et al. that will allow you to roll-back changes. Briefly below:

- `/var/backups/dpkg.status`: this directory keeps a set of log of the last system state prior to an install as follows
- `/var/backups/dpkg.status.0`: is the most recent log prior to a state change (e.g. package install/remove/update ...etc)
- `/var/backups/dpkg.status.?.gz`: are compressed, archived versions of the logs at various points in time, rotated monthly.