# Ubuntu 14.10 desktop missing bars

Tags: unity

When I start my laptop, I'm going to the BIOS settings and booting the laptop with Ubuntu 14.10, while the process, a message shows on a black screen, "…cant read pipe…" There's not enough time to read, but when the system starts, I can only see the desktop, the bars aren't there, I tried to boot as a guest and everything is fine.

Why is this happening?
I've tried to restart the computer (by taking the battery out), because it's the only way to restart…

Comment: What “bars” do you mean? Can you post a screen shot of what you see and describe what you expect to see instead? A log of the boot messages can be found in `/var/log/boog.log` and `/var/log/syslog`. Please [edit] your question to include the aforementioned info to enable other people to help you.

Comment: A few notes: What kind of laptop do you use? I highly doubt it can only be restarted by taking out the battery. Pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del will restart a running Linux and if that doesn't help, press down the power switch of your laptop for 4–10 seconds until it powers down. There should also be a manual coming with your laptop or at least on the manufacturer web site with instructions on how to shut it off or restart it.

Comment: I'm using hp pavilion g6 notebook, when I press CTRL alt delete it's opening what its opening in windows.. Program manager? I don't know. I'm expecting to see the programs bar from the left and the to bar, the hours the battery life, before this happened I tried to open a steam game and it showed an error box says there is an error with the OpenGL.

Comment: Another thing, I can't move anything. Windows just opens and stay there even the top bar with the close maximize and minimize isn't there. I can't do anything, I can't ctrl alt t to open the terminal.

Comment: [The manual](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02770249.pdf) describes how to power off your kind of laptop on page 9. Please [create a screen shot](/q/425789) of what your desktop looks like. Otherwise nobody will be able to tell what the issue is.

Comment: picture of my desktop - http://tinypic.com/r/2nlh1ub/8 http://i57.tinypic.com/2nlh1ub.jpg

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Comment: So i just need to follow the instructions? Even if I have Ubuntu 14.10?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My Guest account was unaffected but in my main account neither Dash nor Unity were visible, and the graphical interface didn't respond to any keystrokes though I could still switch to a TTY interface with Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Unity and Dash seemed to be corrupted in my main account. After trying everything else I found the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506921/how-to-get-back-unity-and-compiz-after-uninstalling-no-launcher-or-dash-on-star).

Use Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get a command-line interface then reinstall the desktop and Unity:

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity`

Comment: Re-installing `ubuntu-desktop` is useless voodoo, because it's a meta-package. Meta-packages contain no files apart from a copyright notice, a changelog, and sometimes a little documentation. Run `dpkg --listfiles ubuntu-desktop` to see for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

If u still have the ubuntu dvd disk or usb drive, just insert it to the computer boot from the dvd or usb it will ask u to reformat or repair ubuntu or fix problem then click on the fix or repair follow the instruction untill it done, that how i get mine fix.

Comment: I don't think a re-installation is necessary. It may also either not fix the problem or delete OP's home directory.