# How to revert back to regular ubuntu instead of lubuntu

Tags: boot, lubuntu, gdm

Here is the story:

I was on Ubuntu 18.04 with the default configuration and display manager.
Then it froze so I pulled the plug by holding down the power button.

After that it would boot normally and the log in screen showed up, I entered my credentials and then the screen went blank.

I searched for a solution. And I fiddled around with many commands and I switched display managers, I tried `lightdm` but I didn't like it so I switched to `gdm3` which supposedly was the default and it worked but after I did `sudo reboot` it went straight to the boot process and it shows `lubuntu` in blue, how do I switch it back because now it's super slow User Interface.

Please help, thanx!

Comment: You mentioned commands, so they'll be in your `history` allowing you to remember what you did so you can reverse it.  *I have my `history` record time & date to aid this process but it doesn't by default*.  If you used gui-frontends to install packages, your `/var/log/apt/history.log` will help you see what you added/removed, but with what you've provided, I don't see what else we can provide as we don't know what you did.

Comment: A re-install (no format) will restore packages, but without format it'll try and preserve your config changes, which may be what is creating your problem thus the problem may not be fixed by re-install (unless clean/format is used).  Regular Ubuntu does not include Lubuntu it implies you've added a lot of changes/packages and you've done more than you've told us.

Comment: Does it load to the login screen at all?  Or does it load directly to Lubuntu?  I use gdm3 with Xubuntu, but I can switch DEs or I can set a default for it to log into.  It if automatically logs in, you can log out and then it will give you the login screen and you can choose the DE from there by clicking your name then choosing by the cogwheel dropdown.

Comment: You left out the part where you installed Lubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I do a system restore?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56095/how-i-do-a-system-restore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing Gnome desktop with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Don't forget to choose lightDM during the installation process. Once it's complete, restart your machine. Login to the gnome Desktop. Remove LXDE.

```
sudo apt remove lubuntu* lxde* openbox lightdm
sudo apt autoremove
sudo reboot
```

Also if you want to remove apps that were installed, you can do so from Ubuntu software, Terminal, or install Synaptic and remove the files from there.